# Apache Spark read Cassandra mixing columns in prepared statements

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

Read from cassandra using apache spark

```
       sparkSession.sqlContext().read()
                .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .option("table", "information_package")
                .option("keyspace", "streaming_keyspace")
                .load().show(false);
```

spark properties for cassandra

```
spark.cassandra.connection.host=localhost
spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms=600000000
spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms=10000
spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms=220000
```

table information_package has about 20 columns

got in cassandra logs:

**prepared statements discarded in the last minute because cache limit reached (15 MB)**

do select from cassandra:

```
select * from system.prepared_statements
```

and got:

```
SELECT "col1", "col2", "col3" FROM "streaming_keyspace"."information_package" WHERE token("col1") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING
SELECT "col1", "col2", "col3" FROM "streaming_keyspace"."information_package" WHERE token("col1") > ?   ALLOW FILTERING

SELECT "col2", "col1", "col3" FROM "streaming_keyspace"."information_package" WHERE token("col1") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING
SELECT "col2", "col1", "col3" FROM "streaming_keyspace"."information_package" WHERE token("col1") > ?   ALLOW FILTERING

SELECT "col3", "col2", "col1" FROM "streaming_keyspace"."information_package" WHERE token("col1") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING
SELECT "col3", "col2", "col1" FROM "streaming_keyspace"."information_package" WHERE token("col1") > ?   ALLOW FILTERING

SELECT "col3", "col1", "col2" FROM "streaming_keyspace"."information_package" WHERE token("col1") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING
SELECT "col3", "col1", "col2" FROM "streaming_keyspace"."information_package" WHERE token("col1") > ?   ALLOW FILTERING
...
```

I see mixing of columns for single select request. The question is why and who is mixing columns for prepared statements in cassandra. And main question what property i should change for stop mixing columns

**upd**
Mixing starts from columns amount = 5

Comment: What version of Spark Cassandra Connector are you using?

Comment: spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

> prepared statements discarded in the last minute because cache limit reached (15 MB)

This means that you're exhausting the prepared statement cache. This is usually due to creating a prepared statement that has concrete values. You can debug if this is the case by inspecting the saved prepared statements in `system.prepared_statements` and looking for duplicates.

As for the mixing of columns, this is just down to how you prepare the statements. From what is described it sounds like statements are being re-prepared numerous times without explicit sorting of the columns used in the statement.

You need to be consistent with how you're defining the prepared statements.